# spring integration in spring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am learning spring integration and activemq. I want to experiment these 2 technologies in a gaming web (Spring MVC) application I am developing.
In my application, a game can be started by a player and invite his friends to participate in the game. All logged on players would get notification (visible on the page) and they can begin the play.
I want to know where does spring-integration fit into this? I was hoping to use it to deal with the moves made by each player and update other players to receive the notifications and accordingly UI can update the relevant content on the page. Any idea how do I design the channel, consumer and provider stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say that your application is WEB, it seems like it would be better to use for your case WebSockets. We have in Spring similar solution on the matter via Spring Messaging: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket, https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-msgsjs.

As far as Spring Websockets solution is beased on Messaging principles (Message, Channel, Handler) from Spring Messaging foundation, and upcoming Spring Integration 4.0 release is besed on the same module, it won't be so difficult to get deal with Integration flow from Websocket layer and vise versa.

HTH